# What kind of protocol is being used here to communicate with PayPal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, paypal

I know that there are various ways to use PayPal's API (SOAP, etc), but I don't know anything about them, so in an attempt to broaden my knowledge on the subject, would you please tell me what is being used in this example from railscasts:

```
   1. def paypal_url(return_url)  
   2.     values = {  
   3.       :business => ’seller_1234111143_biz@asciicasts.com’,  
   4.       :cmd => ’_cart’,  
   5.       :upload => 1,  
   6.       :return => return_url,  
   7.       :invoice => id  
   8.     }  
   9.       
   10.     line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|  
   11.       values.merge!({  
   12.         "amount_#{index + 1}" => item.unit_price,  
   13.         "item_name_#{index + 1}" => item.product.name,  
   14.         "item_number_#{index + 1}" => item.product.identifier,  
   15.         "quantity_#{index + 1}" => item.quantity  
   16.       })  
   17.     end  
   18.     "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.map { |k,v|     "#{k}=#{v}"  }.join("&")  
   19.   end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned this is a get request to PayPal's servers.

Specifically it is a cart upload command - you can read about this here: https://www.x.com/community/ppx/wps. If interested check out the html variables reference on the right hand side of that page. It is those variables that are being sent to PayPal with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple get request over HTTP.  The final request would look something like:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=seller_1234111143_biz@asciicasts.com& cmd=_cart&upload=1...

and so on, which should look somewhat familiar.

Answer (score -2):

Http is the Internet protocol

Comment: Actually HTTP is the World Wide Web protocol (hence "HyperText"). The Internet protocol is TCP/IP.